# Extract the last two elements from a list, no matter the length

Tags: ansible

I have a list of hosts in Ansible, which will always have minimum 3 elements:

```
[server]
apollo
boreas
cerus
```

Using a fact similar to:

```
- name: Set loadbalancer hosts fact
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    loadbalancer_hosts: "{{ groups['server'][1:3] }}"
  run_once: true
```

Will return the last 2 hosts. However, I want to be able to extract the last two hosts automatically if I add additional hosts, later on. For example, if my list of hosts becomes:

```
[server]
apollo
boreas
cerus
chaos
```

`loadbalancer_hosts` should automatically return `cerus` and `chaos` as list.

Comment: Get the number of hosts and do the math accordingly. `total_hosts: "{{ groups['server'] | length }}"` or `total_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | length }}"`

Comment: Thank you, I edited the OP with your proposed solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Array slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing). In Ansible, use the Python syntax:

```yaml
  loadbalancer_hosts: "{{ groups.server[-2:] }}"
```

Given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[server]
apollo
boreas
cerus
chaos
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  loadbalancer_hosts:
  - cerus
  - chaos
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    loadbalancer_hosts: "{{ groups.server[-2:] }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: loadbalancer_hosts
      run_once: true
```